# Passing datasource as parameter in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 2008. We want to convert actuate reports into crystal reports.
In actaute reports we are passing datasource, username and password as parameters and in each section we are using these parameters and will create connection. So that we can  connect dev, test and prod database whenever we want. Like that is that possible to pass datasource as parameter in crystal reports? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to pass the datasource as a parameter like you generally would pass a parameter for a report.

The link below is a C# example of how to change the data source at runtime which may be able to help you work around your issue. Hope it helps.

[Crystal Reports and data Binding at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439475/crystal-reports-and-data-binding-at-run-time)