# SQL Server 2008 R2, Crystal Report and asp.net issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, Crystal Report 13 and Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 Ultimate,

I have created a crystal report and a crystal report viewer but on execution of the software once i click the command button it does not show the report in the viewer, even i cant see the empty report also. i cant see anything no viewer nor and empty report which is strange, i do not understand what is the error. here is my code in the button.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
    using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
    using CrystalDecisions.Reporting;


    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);
        ReportDocument rptLog = new ReportDocument();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
        //    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("stpLogReport", con);
        //    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string Query = "Select * from tblLogReport";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            rptLog.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
            rptLog.SetDataSource(ds);
            rptLog.SetParameterValue("UserName", "zaigham.ali");
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptLog;
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

//  This is a connection string in web.config
    <add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-JOV450P2;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abcvfddde" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Check if you peoples can help me.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Report" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" HasRefreshButton="True" 
            Height="1202px" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelView="ParameterPanel" 
            ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="903px" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show the markup too (where the viewer is embedded)? in the debugger, when you inspect `ds` after `Fill` has executed, is there data?

Comment: can u please let me know how can i see the ds after fill has executed? can u tell me what is markup i do not know too much about these thing, your effort will be appreciated. i would appreciate if you can check my code via teamviewer if you can. i will be thankfull to you.

Comment: sorry I skipped the line where you mentioned that you're on VS2010, there was no datatable insight yet. 1) set a breakpoint on the line after `da.Fill(ds)`, start and click your button, once you're back in VS open the immediate pane and type `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` to see whether there is data. 2) the markup is the designer source code of the ASP ("the html").

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count
'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) i am getting this message.

Comment: my bad, ds is already a datatable. should be `ds.Rows.Count` then. please use the "edit" feature to add the markup section to your post.

Comment: yes it says 30. that means the data is there. now what should be a problem?  i appreciate if you can just see my project via teamviewer i am sure you can rectify the issue. i have edit the post and have add my html their also for the page

Comment: dlatikay!! any luck. can we sort out the issue, their is 30 rows in ds still it does not show the report.

Comment: try to apply the insights of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440002/1132334), especially the advice about "transferring the code from the Load function to the Init function of the Reportviewer object". I think that `AutoDataBind` should be set to false, as you bind explicitely, but I did not yet check documentation to back up this claim.